# How to monitor outgoing HTTP connections in .NET?

Tags: .net, tcp

How does one log all outgoing HTTP connections in .NET from a Windows 7 computer? I can see the connections in Fiddler, but I want my own program to log those connections.

I found [IPGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcpconnections.aspx). But that requires polling. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do what fiddler2 does: Implement a [Layered Service Provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways.

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is one.

[System.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx) tracing is another. I suggest you use implement your own trace writer and you get all information coming to you to log.

System.net tracing does not store all the data, only the first 1024 bytes.

Comment: System.Net tracing looks useful for debugging a managed app. I'm actually looking to log *all* outgoing HTTP connections from all processes on the machine -- using a .NET app. Thanks for the suggestion, however.